# What should I do to make this menu bar work well in Internet Explorer 7 and above?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, menubar

I have a CSS template that I am trying to change it a little bit in order to use it in my website. I am facing a strange problem with it which I don't have any idea about how to fix it. 
The menu bar at the top of the website designed in a such way when the user clicks on one of the options, that options will be inside a rectangle with a dark green color as shown in the following snapshot:

[image]

This rectangle implemented using the following CSS:

```
/* TOP MENU */
#nav{
    position:relative;
    z-index:200;
    padding:0;
    text-align:right
}
#topnav, #topnav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style-position:outside;
}

#topnav{padding:25px 0 0 0; float:right}

#topnav a{
    padding:0 20px 34px 20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#topnav li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
#topnav li.current > a{}

#topnav li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:0 0 0 0px;
    margin:0;
    height:35px;
    line-height:35px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#topnav li.last{padding:0; margin:0}
#topnav li li{
    padding-right:0px;
    display:block;
    line-height:25px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0;
    margin-right:0;
    text-align:left !important;
    float:none;

}
#topnav ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:160px;
    top:58px;
    left:0;
    padding:15px 0 13px 0;
    text-align:left;
    background-position:0 13px !important
}

#topnav li ul a{
    width:130px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 0px;
    padding:8px 15px;
    font-size:12px !important;
    line-height:16px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left !important;
    text-transform:capitalize;

}

#topnav li ul a:hover{}

#topnav ul ul{
    top:0px;
}   

#topnav li ul ul {
    left:160px;
    margin:0px 0 0 0px;
}

#topnav li:hover ul ul, #topnav li:hover ul ul ul, #topnav li:hover ul ul ul ul{
    display:none;
}
#topnav li:hover ul, #topnav li li:hover ul, #topnav li li li:hover ul, #topnav li li li li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
#topnav li.back {}
#topnav li.back {z-index:8;position: absolute;}
#topnav > li a, #topnav > li a:hover, #topnav > li a:visited{z-index:10;position:relative}
```

Also, the movement of this rectangle with the mouse movement depends on the following Javascript files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.lavalamp.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/lavalamp-config.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.easing.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.preloader.js"></script>
```

My problem is most of the machines in my company use **Internet Explorer 7** and the menu doesn't work with it properly. When I clicked in one of these options, nothing changed which means I did not get redirected to another page. Besides that, the rectangle shape keeps to be around the first option only. **Why? And how to fix it?**

Since I am developing as ASP.NET application, I put all the CSS and Javascript files in Master Page and for the menu bar, I developed as a User Control.

Here's a link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zqd8u/) but it is not completed due to the missing of the images.
*Sorry for that but I am not familiar with JSFiddle.*

Comment: Could you add a link to a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to use it and how to add the Javascript files. This application is an intranet web-based application so there is no link to it.

Comment: Is it really important that the rectangle moves over the links? You could also use feature detection so that modern browser use the cool Lava Lamp nav, and older browsers load a traditional nav.

Comment: How? Sorry for asking a lot but I am a new developer and I am seeking for help and useful resources that might be helpful in solving this problem

Comment: I'll post as an answer hold on.

Comment: the rectangle is moving but it was not shown at the top of clicked option. It is stayed on the first option only. WHY? Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: It's because IE7 doesn't support modern web features. Without a link I can't tell you exactly why.

Comment: For now try getting rid of: `<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.lavalamp.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/lavalamp-config.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.lavalamp.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/lavalamp-config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.easing.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.preloader.js"></script>
```

with:

```
<script>
if ($.browser.version < 9.0 && $.browser.msie) {
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.easing.1.1.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.preloader.js"></script><script type="text/javascript"  src="./Scripts/jquery.lavalamp.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/lavalamp-config.js"></script>';
}
else {
    document.getElementById("head")[0].innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.easing.1.1.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.preloader.js">';
}

​​</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```